# What is the best practice to setup multilanguage store (any sql upgrades)?

Tags: magento, locale

It's boring to add store views manually, especially when your store has many languages.
Does anyone use sql upgrade script for adding store views and assigning appropriate locale?
How can I do this via sql upgrade script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full code for adding multiple store views and assigning locale:

```
$defaultStore = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(1);
$websiteId = $defaultStore->getWebsiteId();
$store = Mage::getModel('core/store_group')->load($defaultStore->getGroupId());

$storeViewsData = array(
    'es' => array(
        'name'   => 'Spanish',
        'locale' => 'es_ES',
    ),
    'fr' => array(
        'name'   => 'French',
        'locale' => 'fr_FR',
    ),
    'pt' => array(
        'name'   => 'Portuguese',
        'locale' => 'pt_PT',
    ),
    'it' => array(
        'name'   => 'Italian',
        'locale' => 'it_IT',
    )
    );

    foreach ($storeViewsData as $code => $data) {
    $view = Mage::getModel('core/store');
        $view->setData(array(
            'website_id'    => $websiteId,
            'group_id'      => $store->getId(),
            'name'          => $data['name'],
            'code'          => $code,
            'is_active'     => 1
        ));
        $view->save();

        Mage::getConfig()->reinit();
        Mage::app()->reinitStores();


        $groupsValue = array();
        $groupsValue['locale']['fields']['code']['value'] = $data['locale'];

        Mage::getModel('adminhtml/config_data')
            ->setSection('general')
            ->setWebsite('base')
            ->setStore($code)
            ->setGroups($groupsValue)
            ->save();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Create yourself a custom module (use [Module Creator](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/danieln/extension/1108/modulecreator) extension if you wish) then add this code to your `mysql4-install-0.1.0.php` and modify as appropriate.

```
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();
// Start with a root category

$root_cat = Mage::getModel("catalog/category");
$root_cat->setData(array(
    "name"              => "Store Name",
    "url_key"           => "root",
    "description"       => "Store Name root category",
    "display_mode"      => Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::DM_PRODUCT,
    "default_sort_by"   => Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->getDefaultSortBy(),
    "available_sort_by" => Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->getDefaultSortBy(),
    "is_active"         => 1,
    "is_anchor"         => 0,
    "include_in_menu"   => 0,
    "parent_id"         => 1,
    "path"              => Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load(1)->getPath(),
    "attribute_set_id"  => Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->getDefaultAttributeSetId()
));

try {
    $root_cat->save();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::logException($e->getMessage());
    return;
}

//setup an array of our websites, stores and storeviews
$website_array = array(
    "store_us"  => array(
        "name"          => "Store Name - US",
        "store"         => "Store Name - US Store",
        "store_view"    => array(
            "name"      => "English (US)",
            "code"      => "store_us_en"
        )
    ),
    "store_au"  => array(
        "name"          => "Store Name - AU",
        "store"         => "Store Name - AU Store",
        "store_view"    => array(
            "name"      => "English (AU)",
            "code"      => "store_au_en"
        )
    ),
    "store_de"  => array(
        "name"  => "Store Name - UK",
        "store" => "Store Name - UK Store",
        "store_view"    => array(
            "name"      => "UK",
            "code"      => "store_uk_en"
        )
    ),
);

$i = 1;

foreach ($website_array as $site_code => $site_details) {

    try {

        // First, the website

        $site = Mage::getModel("core/website");
        $site->setData(array(
            "code"          => $site_code,
            "name"          => $site_details["name"],
            "is_default"    => (($i == 1) ? 1 : 0),
            "sort_order"    => $i
        ));
        $site->save();

        // then attach the store to the website

        $store = Mage::getModel("core/store_group");
        $store->setData(array(
            "website_id"        => $site->getId(),
            "root_category_id"  => $root_cat->getId(),
            "name"              => $site_details["store"]
        ));
        $store->save();

        // Set this store as default for the website

        $site->setDefaultGroupId($store->getId());
        $site->save();

        // Finally, the store view

        $view = Mage::getModel("core/store");
        $view->setData(array(
            "website_id"    => $site->getId(),
            "group_id"      => $store->getId(),
            "name"          => $site_details["store_view"]["name"],
            "code"          => $site_details["store_view"]["code"],
            "sort_order"    => $i,
            "is_active"     => 1
        ));
        $view->save();

        // Set this store view as default for the store

        $store->setDefaultStoreId($view->getId());
        $store->save();


    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::logException($e->getMessage());
    }

    $i++;
}
```

HTH,
JD

Comment: Thanks! And how to set locale for store view?

Answer (score 2):

You can set locale for your store view in this way:

```
$groupsValue = array();
$groupsValue['locale']['fields']['code']['value'] = 'uk_UA';

Mage::getModel('adminhtml/config_data')
    ->setSection('general')
    ->setWebsite('base')
    ->setStore($storeViewCode)
    ->setGroups($groupsValue)
    ->save();
```